# ViewController not displaying contents when embedded in UIView

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swift2, ios9

I have a scrollview which contains two containers (UIViews). One UIView contains a UITableView which displays correctly and another ViewController. The viewController has an image which fills it completely. However, when adding the View Controller if I set a background color that shows up.

[image]

```
//
//  SideBarViewController.swift
//  Sidebar
//
//  Created by Satyajit Sarangi on 12/10/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Satyajit Sarangi. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SideBarViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    let menuTableView = UITableView()
    let sideBarContainerView = UIView()
    let mainContainerView = UIView()
    let testContainerView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // Create a dictionary for the views for the visual format language
        let containerViewsDict = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("sidebar_container", sideBarContainerView), ("main_container", mainContainerView))
        // let scrollViewDict = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("scrollview", scrollView))

        // Create two container


        // Add the scroll view
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.frame)

        // Set Properties for scrollview
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, view.frame.height)

        // sideBarContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        scrollView.addSubview(sideBarContainerView)
        scrollView.addSubview(mainContainerView)

        setupMainContainerView()
        setupSideBarTableView()


        // Add the Scroll View
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[sidebar_container]-5-[main_container]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:  0), metrics: nil, views: containerViewsDict)

        let scrollview_verticalConstraints1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[sidebar_container]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: containerViewsDict)

        let scrollview_verticalConstraints2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[main_container]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: containerViewsDict)

        sideBarContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
        scrollView.addConstraints(scrollview_verticalConstraints1)
        scrollView.addConstraints(scrollview_verticalConstraints2)

        // Add constraints for the Scroll View
        // let scrollview_constraint_v = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollview]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: scrollViewDict)

        // let scrollview_constraint_h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollview]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: scrollViewDict)

        // scrollView.addConstraints(scrollview_constraint_v)
        // scrollView.addConstraints(scrollview_constraint_h)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)

        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), animated: true)
    }


    // MARK: Set UI Properties
    func setupSideBarTableView() {
        menuTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, scrollView.frame.height)
        menuTableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)
        menuTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        sideBarContainerView.addSubview(menuTableView)

        let dict = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("menu_table", menuTableView))
        let constraint_h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[menu_table]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: dict)
        let constraint_v = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[menu_table]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: dict)

        sideBarContainerView.frame = menuTableView.frame

        sideBarContainerView.addConstraints(constraint_h)
        sideBarContainerView.addConstraints(constraint_v)
    }

    func setupMainContainerView() {
//        testContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, scrollView.frame.height)
//        testContainerView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)
//        testContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        let testContainerView = TestViewController()
        self.addChildViewController(testContainerView)

        mainContainerView.addSubview(testContainerView.view)

//        let dict = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("test_container", testContainerView))
//        let constraint_h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[test_container]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: dict)
//        let constraint_v = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[test_container]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: dict)

        mainContainerView.frame = testContainerView.view.frame
//        mainContainerView.addConstraints(constraint_h)
//        mainContainerView.addConstraints(constraint_v)
        testContainerView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

The view controller looks like this... and the code for it is pasted below. As can be seen, the story board has the image and the viewDidLoad sets it to yellow. However, if I turn off background color, no image is seen.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }
}
```

How do I get the TestControllerView to display the views inside it?

Comment: Even when we solve the mystery of the stolen Mona Lisa, this code features a couple of strange (and I would have thought, problematic) things. For example, this has a table view inside a scroll view; this has a mix of manual `frame` settings and auto-layout; etc. I'm happy to suggest how to simplify this, if you'd like, but frankly I'm having trouble reverse engineering the desired UI. Is it just a tableview on the left and a image images that you can scroll through on the right? Or is it just pick an image name on the left and show the image on the right? What precisely is the desired UX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating the `TestViewController` like so:

```
let testContainerView = TestViewController()
```

That will not use the storyboard. If you want to use the storyboard, you have give that scene a "storyboard id" in Interface Builder, and then you can programmatically to do something like:

```
let testContainerView = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestViewController storyboard id here")
```

By the way, when you have these sorts of problems, it's useful to run the app from Xcode and then use the view debugger:

[image]

That lets you dynamically inspect the view hierarchy (so you can confirm whether something's really missing or just possibly off screen or otherwise not visible).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me give that a try. But is there a way not to use the storyboard ? Will that work somehow ?

Comment: I thought the problem was that you had the Mona Lisa image in the storyboard scene and you were wondering where it was. If you want the storyboard scene, you have to use storyboard. Perhaps I misunderstood the question. But, sure you can do it programmatically with no storyboard if you want. But like I said in my comment under your question, I was hoping you could clarify what you're trying to do...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So let me clarify the question. If I create a ViewController with StoryBoard, is it necessary to give it a story board ID ? Now that I think about it, the class itself doesn't have any idea that an image is embedded in the TestViewController so I don't see it. However, storyboard knows about it and so if invoked by story board then it would know about the image and render it. Is that correct ?

Comment: I assigned a storyboard id to the view controller however, when I try to invoke it programmatically like you suggested it always returns a nil. Any idea why ? I made sure that the storyboard id matches in the IB and the code. The only thing I can think of is that the SideBarViewController is completely done programmatically with no storyboard.

Comment: I think the reason was because the view controller had no instance of the right storyboard.. This worked... Thanks Rob....                                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let testContainerView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testViewControllerID")